# Xcode app design - loop easier?

Tags: xcode

I'm pretty new to programming and want some advice on the basic app structure so forgive me if this is pretty obvious.

The main part of the app is a series of 20 pairs of views which the users moves through sequentially (1a,1b,2a,2b,3a etc). Each a view and b view have the same layout as other a/b's but have different image, audio and text.

I could set out all 40 views in storyboard in one long line but that seems like I'm duplicating a lot of work (as well as creating a larger size app) although it would be conceptually very simple (and more stable?)

Alternatively I could just have two views (a and b) with all the content and some sort of counter so that Xcode would know which content to serve up depending on where the user is in the sequence. What would be the easiest way to implement this? I'm afraid however that this could also get unwieldy and perhaps keeping it simple really is the way to go.

Any advice gratefully received.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Design is totally dependent on complexity of screens not on the number of screen. If Screen won't have much variation then you can go for second approach having only 2 views and conditionally loading the data.

Alternatively if you want to go with approach first you won't need to duplicate all the steps. You can programatically create two super class which contains all the functionalities, and the part which varries for that you can create separate class(Inheritance concept). This will make the thing easier, you can reuse the code as well as increase the maintainability of app.